# Nodejs/mongodb- Checking if a user has Admin privileges (token based auth)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, express, jwt

In my express/mongoose app I'm defining verifyOrdinaryUser function to check if a user is authenticated on a server. Which works well, however I've defined verifyAdmin function below to check if a user has admin privileges also (I'm using passport-local-mongoose module to define user Schemas).
As you can see user's token is checked in verifyOrdinaryUser() function, it will load a new property named decoded to the request object which I'm trying to reuse in verifyAdmin, and that's when I'm getting the following error in postman.

```
{
  "message": "Cannot read property '_doc' of undefined",
  "error": {}
}
```

The following is the

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); 
var config = require('../config.js');

exports.getToken = function (user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, {
        expiresIn: 3600
    });
};

exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('No token provided!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
};

exports.verifyAdmin = function(req,res,next){
    if(req.decoded._doc.admin !== true)  {
        return next(err);
    }else {
        return next();
    }
};
```

I'm sure I've messed up something in the verifyAdmin function. 
Middleware order looks right to me
Suggestions are welcome

thank you

EDIT: Middleware goes here from app.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// passport config
var User = require('./models/user');
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/dishes',dishRouter);
app.use('/promotions',promoRouter);
app.use('/leadership',leaderRouter);
```

Comment: Quick sanity check: what order are you `app.use`ing the middleware?

Comment: Express middleware order

Comment: Could you post the lines where you `app.use`? I know you said it looks right, but I can't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Just edited the question. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Hmm... I still don't see where this middleware gets `app.use`ed. :) You've exported 3 functions that can be used as middleware. At some point you should be doing `app.use(foo.verifyOrdinaryUser);` and then `app.use(foo.verifyAdmin);`, right?

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first but user authentication worked without requiring the module in the app middleware. (maybe because I have required those auth modules in the route files  which are already imported in app middleware ? ) Really confusing to me

Comment: Let me use the authentication modules in the app, as you said, I guess it's well worth trying. I'll get back to you

Comment: Tried app.use-ing the middleware but node won't even connect to the server.
Gives me the following err- 
 var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Answer (score 8):

I am in the coursera class as well.  The thorough explanations provided by the other answers clearly show a deep understanding of these tools, but I think they might be overkill for this assignment.  To quote Professor Jogesh's response on the coursera message board to a thread with a similar issue:

"Do you make sure that you first called verifyOrdinaryUser before you called verifyAdmin? The two have to be chained one after another.

From the error, it looks like req.decoded is not available. It means that verifyOrdinaryUser was not called. This function adds the decoded property to req."

Your code from verify.js and app.js look correct and shouldn't need changing.  However, when calling your verifyAdmin function in your routers, be sure to always include verifyAdmin after calling verifyOrdinaryUser like so:

```
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req, res, next) {
```

Because req.decode is established in verifyOrdinaryUser, when you call verifyAdmin without verifyOrdinaryUser first, your decode remains undefined.  You can make your verifyAdmin function more thorough like the other answers suggest, but again, it isn't necessary for this assignment.

Answer (score 5):

I also stuck in the same problem. Here is the snippet of verify.js for verifyAdmin()

```
exports.verifyAdmin = function(req, res, next){
// check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

// verifies secret and checks exp
jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
if (err) {
  var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
  err.status = 401;
  return next(err);
} else {
  // They are an admin
  if (decoded._doc.admin){
    return next();
  } else {
    // They are not an admin
    var err = new Error('You are not authorized to perform this operation!');
    err.status = 403;
    return next(err);
  }
}
});
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I´m doing the same Coursera course that you are. I have just finished this assignment! You should do this:
 - In your verify.js file add this:

```
exports.verifyAdmin = function (req, res, next) {

    if (req.decoded._doc.admin == true) {
        next();
    } else {
        // if the user is not admin
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('You are not authorized to perform this operation!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }

};
```

Then in your router files (like dishRouter.js) you should use this middleware injections:

```
dishRouter.route('/')
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req,res,next){
    //res.end('Will send all the dishes to you!');
    Dishes.find({}, function (err, dish) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(dish);
    });
})

.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req, res, next){
    //res.end('Will add the dish: ' + req.body.name + ' with details: ' + req.body.description);
    Dishes.create(req.body, function (err, dish) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Dish created!');
      var id = dish._id;

      res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      res.end('Added the dish with id: ' + id);
    });
})

.delete(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req, res, next){
    //res.end('Deleting all dishes');
    Dishes.remove({}, function (err, resp) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(resp);
    });
});
```

Comment: I followed all of these codes and I am still getting the error. Here is some of my code in dishRouter and users respectively:
.delete(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function (req, res, next)
and
if(req.decoded._doc.admin === true){

Answer (score 3):

your code looks fine, only must edit the verifyAdmin function to this:

```
exports.verifyAdmin = function(req, res, next){
    var isAdmin = req.decoded._doc.admin
    if (isAdmin) {
        return next();
    }
    else {
        // if user is not admin
        // return an error
        var err =  new Error ('You are not autorized to perform this   operation!');
        err.status =  403;
        return next(err);

    }
}
```

In your case the error is because the variable "error" is not defined in the code.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

**req.decoded._doc.admin** NOT WORKING

But you can use this function.

> [jwt.decode(token [, options]);](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtdecodetoken--options)

Example for course, it works for me:

```js
exports.verifyAdmin = function(req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // get the decoded payload and header "req.decoded._doc.admin" NOT WORKING
    var decAdmin = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err || !decAdmin.payload._doc.admin) {
                var err = new Error('You are not authorized to perform this operation!');
                err.status = 403;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('No token provided!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried and this worked for me. It is almost the same with the verifyOrdinaryUser code except if (err || !decAdmin.payload._doc.admin) line. But good point to catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of those who might not understand what your code is doing I will give a long explanation, for your specific error please scroll to the bottom of this post

---

```
 if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
```

Sets the req.decoded property to the output of the verification from jwt.query. This returns a JSON object which has useful information from the result of the authentication. The jwt.query apart from authentication the encrypted password also check the user  has admin flag set and here are the results it returns (in this case found true)
[image]

The decoded._doc.admin field is of interest to us. So you can use something like

```
jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                  if (decoded._doc.admin) {
                  req.admin = true;
                }
                next();
            }
        });
```

Now there is no need for further queries to database and in the next middleware you can make use of this. In your case you have chosen to send the entire decoded object which is also not wrong but unncessary. The next middleware is your function to verify if the admin property was true from the previous results.

```
verifyAdmin = function(req,res,next){
    if (req.admin) {
      console.log("Admin active");
    next();
  }
    else {
      var error  = new Error('You do not have admin privileges!');
      error.status = 401;
      return next(error)
    }
  };
```

You need to use the two functions together in the Routers

```
.post(verifyOrdinaryUser, verifyAdmin, function(req, res, next){
```

The first verify will check for Login and the 2nd one will check for Admin. The results are available in the first function itself and you can complete it in one function also.

Your code for the verifyAdmin was

```
exports.verifyAdmin = function(req,res,next){
    if(req.decoded._doc.admin !== true)  {
        return next(err);
    }else {
        return next();
    }
};
```

may suffer from - err not being available but you error message

```
{
  "message": "Cannot read property '_doc' of undefined",
  "error": {}
}
```

indicates you do not have the req.decoded set in the first place. Most likely you called verifyAdmin before calling verifyOridinaryUser.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone was using the recommended signature of:

```
exports.jwtPassport = passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,
    (jwt_payload, done) => {
        console.log("JWT payload: ", jwt_payload);
        User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload._id}, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            else if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            }
            else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));

exports. verifyOrdinaryUser = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});
```

then, you might notice that the 'user' object is returned from the strategy. Thus, by setting:

```
exports.verifyAdmin = function(params, err, next) {
    if (params.user.admin){
      return next();
    } else {
      var err = new Error('Only administrators are authorized to perform this operation.');
      err.status = 403;
      return next(err);
    }
};
```

After which the following authorization signature in the route should work:

```
...
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req,res,next){...}
```

Though, as Emmanuel P. mentioned, there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I'm guess error you're getting after `app.use`ing 
`verifyAdmin` is because it was called. So we did `app.use(verifyAdmin())` instead of `app.use(verifyAdmin)`.

Note that by calling this without any parameters, `req` will obviously be `undefined`.

What we want is for *Express* to do the calling. We just need to stuff this function in somewhere.

Middleware is fun.

---

So just to recap, if I'm tracking this right, I think what we've got is something like the following:

1. We have an `app.js` (or maybe `index.js` or `server.js`) that does all the `app.use` router plumbing
2. `app.js` already has Passport set up, which is taking care of authentication.
3. We also have a module with the following middleware exported:

   - `verifyOrdinaryUser`
   - `verifyAdmin`

Let's call this module `foo.js`.

4. We want to use `verifyOrdinaryUser` and `verifyAdmin` in places we only want logged in users and admin users to go

I'll go ahead and assume that we don't want users to be able to get anywhere but the landing page, `app.use('/', routes);`, without being logged in. So, *after* this line, let's add `app.use(verifyOrdinaryUser)`:

```
app.use('/', routes);

// verifyOrdinaryUser will now be called before any middleware used AFTER this statement
app.use(foo.verifyOrdinaryUser);

app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/dishes',dishRouter);
app.use('/promotions',promoRouter);
app.use('/leadership',leaderRouter);
```

Now let's assume that only admins get access to the `/users` section. To do that, we'll put the `verifyAdmin` middleware in front of JUST the `users` router. Now our code looks like this:

```
app.use('/', routes);

// verifyOrdinaryUser will now be called before any middleware used AFTER this statement
app.use(foo.verifyOrdinaryUser);

// Call the verifyAdmin middleware BEFORE any middleware in the `users` router
app.use('/users', foo.verifyAdmin, users);

app.use('/dishes',dishRouter);
app.use('/promotions',promoRouter);
app.use('/leadership',leaderRouter);
```

This code makes a lot of assumptions, but you should be able to adapt it.

All that said, something about req.decoded._doc seems a little off in the first place. Shouldn't Passport be handling the `verifyOrdinaryUser` user part?

Comment: I am assigning different privileges to different http requests, which is done in ...Router.js files and that's where I had to call middleware something like the following 
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req,res,next){...}
so after calling verifyOrdinaryUser it would return the decoded in the request which I could make use of when I would call verifyAdmin. 
I was calling verifyAdmin without first checking if user is authenticated, in other words first calling the verifyOrdinaryUser.
Thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: @ForkInSpace, in my case your way only worked for admin user. In the ordinary user it gives following error:

{
  "message": "err is not defined",
  "error": {}
}

Answer (score 1):

I am assigning different privileges to different http requests, which is done in ...Router.js (promoRouter.js, etc) files and that's where I had to call middleware something like the following

```
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req,res,next){...}
```

so after calling verifyOrdinaryUser it would return the decoded in the request which I could make use of when I would call verifyAdmin. I was calling verifyAdmin without first checking if user is authenticated, in other words first calling the verifyOrdinaryUser.

Answer (score 1):

Where are in the same coursera course.

As ForkInSpace says, if it is not defined it is because your code didn't pass the first middleware

In week 3, we didn't use the *.all(middleware)* syntax, and explicitely defined all middleware for each operation

```
route('/')
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req,res,next){...}
.put(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req,res,next){...}
.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req,res,next){...}
```

In week 4, the professor introduced the *.all(middleware)* which simplifies the code.

```
route('/')
.all(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser)
.get(function(req,res,next){...}
.put(Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req,res,next){...}
.post( Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req,res,next){...}
```

but if you , like myself, didn't copy/paste the code provided in the course, but type it, you will have probably missed this. and need to update your whole code to work

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.log()` to see what the decoded actually is. You will find that it is your document stored in a "data" object.

Then you can just use `decoded.data.admin` to check it.

Edit:
This is because my "get token" looks like this.

```
exports.getToken = function (user) {
    return jwt.sign({**data:user**}, config.secretKey, {
        expiresIn: 3600
    });
};
```

This small change will make things very easy.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is due to the fact there is no `_doc` under `decoded`, the right call should be as per the following,

```
req.decoded.data.admin
```

To make sure of what I'm saying, just add `console.log(req.decoded)` somewhere in your `verifyAdmin`function and you should find an output similar to the following on your console

```
MAC:passport username$ npm start
...
Connected correctly to server
{ data: 
   { _id: '59e011e9209e2613c5492b1d',
     salt: '...',
     hash: '...',
     username: 'username',
     __v: 0,
     admin: false },
  iat: 1508012930,
  exp: 1508016530 }

GET /dishes 401 18.242 ms - 70
```

Hence, your code shall be as per the following,

```js
exports.verifyAdmin = function (req, res, next) {

    if (req.decoded.data.admin == true) { //NOTICE THE CHANGE "_doc --> data"
        next();
    } else {
        // if the user is not admin
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('You are not authorized to perform this operation!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

Have fun ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.verifyAdmin = ((req,res,next) =>{
        const name = req.body.username
        console.log(name)
        User.findOne({username: name},(err,user) => { 
            if(err) {
                next(err)
            }
            else if(!user) {
                next(new Error("user not found"))
            }
            else {
                if(!user.admin) {
                    next(new Error("you are not an admin"))
                }
                else {
                    next()
                }
            }                         
        });
    });
```

it worked in my case. You can use this function after verifying the user as a normal user.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
exports.verifyAdmin = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.decoded._doc.admin){
      return next();
  }else{
      var err = new Error('Not an Admin =.=');
      err.status = 401;
      return next(err);
  }
 };
```

As verifyOrdinaryUser will be called first, req.decode would contain the decoded details which can be used to verify the status of admin.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your verify admin code, it's correct it just happens to be that the "req.decoded._doc.admin" doesn't work anymore. The new hierarchy is "req.decoded.admin". To check and also ascertain the true hierarchy you can console.log(req.decoded).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble. I have seen so many questions but no clear cut answer for the beginners. here, I am sharing my approach. I am using simply if statement i.e. `if req.user.admin == true`. I am sharing portion of my code as an example of getting users list allowed to only admin:

```
router.get('/', authenticate.verifyUser, function (req, res, next) {
  User.find({}, (err, users) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send('something went swrong');
      next();
    } else if (req.user.admin == true) {
      res.json(users);
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 401;
      res.send('You are not authorized  to perform this');
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I am just starting the assignment - was having a fever on the weekend after getting dental - Now I have sat down the last hour and tried to kick the assignment into gear - and I am at the stage I you guys were - I think maybe editing the mongo db with robomongo resets the token - that's what is causing my verify admin to fail - i think anyway - i am taking a break before continuing